# Configure Intellij to use a Jvm of a guest VM, it's possible?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to know if it's possible to use intellij in a host machine
for compile and build java source code that resides in a guest
VM.

For example, I'm using a windows machine with virtual box. If I preffer to 
install Intellij in this OS and keep the source code on guest OS (ubuntu 
running on Virtual Box), where are java and maven configured. So I would be 
able to use the java/maven of ubuntu for deal with code there are on 
ubuntu too but using de IDE remotely.

In this scenario I just to know if I could set the IDE preferences to use
a java compiler and interpreter and the maven in a remote machine/VM

It's make sense?

If this possibility exists, the is a resource for reading about it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "guest" VM?

Comment: Define VM: Do you mean a java VM or a Virtual Maschine, like VM-Ware Maschines?

Comment: Mount guest VM drive, configure a project on top of it, build. What is the specific problem that you have?

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I want to use java and javac of a remote machine, or OS guest that runs in the Virtual Box

Comment: You can't compile with IDEA with javac running on a different machine or VM, however if OS is the same, you can try to use JDK installed in the VM, but it will still run on the host.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood it's not possible as IntelliJ will need to use local JVM installed on host computer. It cannot use JVM of a remote or Virtual PC.